# Calling a method from multiple component

Tags: arrays, angular, httprequest

I have a method that makes http get request from a url, this method gets called from multiple components, each call is making the http request, so I have stored the result in an array to return the array on the second call and not make the http request again, but it is not returning the array, its making the http request again.

Here is my code:

```
export class ProductsService {

  public currency: string = '';    
  public products: Product[];

  // Initialize 
  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private toastrService: ToastrService) {
  }

  // Get Products
  public getProducts(): Observable<Product[]> {
    return this.getAllProducts();
  }

  private getAllProducts(): Observable<Product[]> {
    if (this.products) {
      return of(this.products);
    } else {
      return this.getIp().pipe(
        switchMap(country => {
          this.currency = this.getCurrency(country);
          return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/products/getAllProducts?currency=' + this.currency).pipe(
            map((res: any) => {
              this.products = res;
              return this.products;
            })
          );
        })
      );
    }
  }

  private getIp() {
    return this.http.get<any>(('http://ip-api.com/json/?fields=countryCode')).pipe(
      map(r => r.countryCode)
    );
  }

  private getCurrency(country: string): string {
    let currency;
    if (country === 'JO') {
      currency = 'JOD';
    } else if (country === 'AE') {
      currency = 'AED';
    } else if (country === 'SA') {
      currency = 'SAR';
    } else if (country === 'GB') {
      currency = 'GBP';
    } else if (country === 'DE') {
      currency = 'EUR';
    } else if (country === 'KW') {
      currency = 'KWD';
    } else if (country === 'EG') {
      currency = 'EGP';
    } else {
      currency = 'USD';
    }
    return currency;
  }


}
```

what am I doing wrong here why the method is making the http request again after the first call, shouldn't the array be filled and returned?

Please note that the components are calling the method getProducts() in the ngOnInit()

Comment: look at this example it might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55014294/how-to-prevent-calling-same-api-in-different-components/55063735#55063735

Answer (score 0):

You are returning the get which is an observable. Each time these methods are called they begin a new subscription to the endpoints.

```
public getProducts(): Observable<Product[]> {
  return this.getAllProducts();
}

private getAllProducts(): Observable<Product[]> {
  if (this.products) {
    return of(this.products);
  } else {
    return this.getIp().pipe(
      switchMap(country => {
        this.currency = this.getCurrency(country);
        return this.http.get('http:/ <== this is an observable
```

You need a service to sync this stuff.

I have an example **service for simple state** that I used to sync URL params for many components on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/state-with-simple-service?file=src%2Fapp%2Fstate.service.ts) that may help you.